# Pyspark issue with timestamps cast when reading MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, pyspark, amazon-redshift, apache-spark-sql, spark-redshift

```
Python 2.7
Pyspark 2.2.1
JDBC format for MySQL->Spark DF
For writing Spark DF-> AWS Redshift i am using the `Spark-Redshift` driver from Databricks.
```

I am reading data into Spark from MySQL tables for my application, due to the context and depending on the input arguments i need to get either all records that were updated before today OR only the records that were updated until the requested date (included).

```
spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "url")
            .option("driver", driver)
            .option("dbtable", query)
            .load()
```

and the query is

```
if days > 0:
    get_date = date.today() - timedelta(days)
    query = "(SELECT * FROM {} WHERE CAST({}.updatedAt AS date) >= DATE('{}') " \
            "AND CAST({}.updatedAt AS date) < CURDATE()) AS t".format(table, table, get_date, table)
elif days == 0:
    query = "(SELECT * FROM {} WHERE CAST({}.updatedAt AS date) < CURDATE() " \
            "OR updatedAt IS NULL) AS t".format(table, table)
```

This timestamp column is discarded as soon as the data are read into Spark dataframes and the ETL contains no other timestamp-related manipulations. The final step is to write the manipulated records to AWS Redshift tables.

My problem is that SOMETIMES the application crashes with a 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp` when writing to Redshift, but i guess the issue comes from converting when reading and is just Spark lazy execution that gives the exception when writing to Redshift (there are no timestamp or date columns in the target Redshift tables whatsoever)

In the last month and for 4 different jobs that run daily i got this exception in the logs about 15% of the time and then the jobs failed, but it runs fine most of the time which is making it impossible to reproduce the issue or debug further.

I suspect the String-> Timestamp casting within the SQL query creates the problem, but i am not sure how i can achieve the same in another way that will not throw this exception. Any help greatly appreciated!

More stacktrace info:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o827.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
```

and

```
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 601 in stage 93.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 601.3 in stage 93.0 (TID 5282, url, executor 5): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftWriter$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RedshiftWriter.scala:234)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftWriter$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RedshiftWriter.scala:233)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftWriter$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RedshiftWriter.scala:252)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftWriter$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RedshiftWriter.scala:248)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:254)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:259)
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, there is some issue with the spark redshift databricks library, and error happens SOMETIMES when writing to Redshift. I hope this query gets more attention from spark redshift developers.
Here is one issue which addresses the same thing:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/435